# QTableView - align number with one letter suffix on decimal point

Tags: qt

I need to display special numerical values  in QTableView. The values have two possible formats: short for example `'12.34'` and wide `'12.34W'` . The number begins with one or two places before the point, then follows the decimal point, then two decimal places and  finally optional letter 'W'. The requirement is to align numbers on the decimal point. Centering is not nice enough.

Is this possible in qt?

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that you have lower level techniques at your disposal.
You could always `sprintf()`. And then left/right justify string displays. Some boilerplate will be needed if you intend to work with those values.
Something like `sprintf(string, "%-.2f%c", value, (isWide) ? 'W' : ' ');`

Comment: Is correct only if @danatel uses fixed-width (monospace) font. For proportional fonts, the assumption that 'W' has the same typographical width as a space is questionable.

Comment: No, I do not use monospaced font. A 'W' is significantly wider than a space.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I agree with you. Just I don't see how does this affect alignment on decimal point. Especially if `MinimumSizeHint` is sufficiently large

Comment: @friendzis If right align is used then decimal point is positioned either width('W') + 2 * width('0') or width(' ') + 2 * width('0') from the right. If left align is used then either 2*width('0') or  1 * width('0') from the left (if number < 9.99). Not aligned in either case.